# Trading machine with item selection

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm trying to build a trading machine in SMP where players should be able to pay a fixed price to get a item they selected (in my case music discs). My setup looks like this:
[image: front]
[image: back]

It should work like this:

- a player selects a item with the "up" and "down" buttons
- the player puts the "payment" (for example 10 diamonds) in the ender chest
- the diamonds are transferred in another chest and the item the player selected appears in the ender chest

The items are stored in an separate room where the bundled cable goes. The other ender chest is also there.

My questions are:

1. What could I use as indicator which item is selected?
2. What engines/wiring/pipes would be needed to pull the diamonds out of the chest, check if the right amount is paid, and put the selected item in the chest?

The modpack I use is **Direwolf20**.

Comment: isn't there actual trade items in the DW pack? I havent played it in a while but I recall something like "trade-o-mat" existing

Comment: @JLaBella There are 2 items, Trade-O-Mat and trade station, but both would not fit my purpose. I would need to place 12 Trade-O-Mats and place 10 diamonds and 1 record (which will not be traded) in every single one. Same is with the trade station.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use computers to display and select which item is chosen. For the logic of the system itself you could use turtles (as they interface very well with computers thanks to wireless).

For example, the display could look something like this:

```
select the item you wish to buy:
1: music disc (5d)
2: lapatron crystal (10d) 
3: note block (2d)
4: thaumium ingot (3d)
input the selection number: _
```

then you would have a turtle who receives the input number, matches it to the item ID. and calls a pull (IIRC) command to the inventory.

I'm sorry that this sounds incredibly complicated and not very descriptive, I don't have FTB on hand to test simpler solutions myself.

Comment: with touch screen you don't even need the player to access the computer

Comment: very true, but i think a touch display is even more difficult than a simple input no?

Comment: no it's just look and right click on the button

Comment: I know that, but to set one up

Comment: dw20 has a button api that will make it easier

Comment: So how do I write such a program? How can a computer detect redstone pulses and forward commands to a turtle?

Comment: I would suggest reading the appropriate wikis for that and finding video tutorials on youtube. I'm sure DireWolf20 was plenty of vdieos on computer/turtle programming you can use for resource. Sorry I can't directly help. Perhaps ask a separate question to get some other experts.

Comment: @JLaBella I've asked a separate question, this programming issue really differs from what I asked first.